# Prove property of adjoint: $(\mathcal{A}^{-1})^*=(\mathcal{A}^*)^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I'm trying to prove it like any other property of adjoint. So, I need to prove following equality: $(\mathcal{A}^{-1}x, y)=(x, \mathcal({A}^{-1})^*y)$.

I know it's very basic, but how to prove this equality?

Or maybe this property of adjoint is proved in different way?

Thanks.

Comment: You asked this [recently](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804011/prove-mathcala-1-mathcala-1-if-mathcala-is-invert).

Comment: But I deleted it and that was unclear question.

Comment: You do *not* have to prove that equality you say in order to prove your result: that equality is true for **any** operator and, in fact, it is just the definition of adjoint operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint based on the uniqueness of inverse of a matrix, assuming we work on an inner product linear space $\;V\;$ and, of course, on $\;\langle Au,v\rangle=\langle u, A^*v\rangle\;$ and $\;(A^*)^*=A\;$:

$$\forall\,u,v\in V:\;\langle\, A^*(A^{-1})^*u,v\,\rangle=\langle\,(A^{-1})^*u,Av\,\rangle=\langle\,u,A^{-1}Av\,\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle\implies A^*(A^{-1})^*=I$$

so...

Comment: So I just need to prove that $\mathcal{A}^*$ has inverse?

Comment: Well, many times one does this exercise *after* knowing already that $\;A\;$ invertible $\;\iff A^*\;$ invertible, but the above in fact proves both this and that the inverse of $\;A^*\;$ is $\;(A^{-1})^*\;$